# Application doesn't work on another computer (Couldn't load file or assembly)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I run the same exe file on another computer, but it gives error.
The application works on my pc, but does not work on user's pc.
I try to compile the app in other development machine and it is work well, the problem is my app doesn't work on user's pc.

`Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecision.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Platform : vb.net(visual studio 2008)

How to solve this error?
Do I need to install additional software to the users pc?

Answer (score 2):

You may install Crystal reports redistributable in the user PC. That will make your app will work correctly on user PC.

You may read more and download the relevant redistributable package for you app using the following link:

http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp#08

Hope this helps...

Comment: From what i found on the internet this is probably the correct answer. And the error appears on other pc an not yours because your pc has VS which includes Crystal Reports fully integrated. The right setup of Crystal Reports must be on your pc in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\CrystalReports10_5".

Comment: Yeah, the reason is true... But it s good to use a redistributable with your setup...

Answer (score 1):

Sozai,

You are missing CR runtime on users machine. Just install crystal reports runtime on users machine.

Hope this will fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

This assembly `CrystalDecision.Shared` is not installed on the other machine and will need to be for it to work.

Comment: i need to install crystal report in the users pc??

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with Crystal for year, but this should work in general.

Add a new Setup project to your solution. It should detect your dependencies, and allow you to build an msi-package for installation that contains the stuff your application needs.

Comment: how to add new setup project??

Comment: Right-click on your solution in the solution explorer, choose "Add" ->New Project-> Setup and deployment -> Setup project

Comment: i cant find "new project" in "Add"

Comment: I'm suspecting that you might have a different version of VS 2008 than me, I have "New project" as the first menu item under "Add".

Answer (score 0):

> open up the references of your project,
>   and for each Crystal* reference
>   listed, set its “Copy Local“ property
>   to “true“.  This will copy the DLLs
>   into your bin folder, and might help
>   distribute them.

[Source](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/rjdudley/archive/2005/05/22/2597.aspx)

Comment: i set it to true & compile, but still same

Comment: Have you copied all the files in the debug\bin folder to the user PC ? If Yes and it does not work, the best solution is to install redistributable packages of crystal reports, using the link Dulini Atapattu suggests in the answers.